# iOS5 how to get device orientation from CMAttitude using CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-location, augmented-reality, core-motion

I'm building an **augmented reality game in iOS5** on devices that support gyroscopes.

I want to use `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical` to map the device orientation and find out which `CLLocation` the device is looking toward. This is a new orientation available in iOS5 based on sensor fusion algorithms. It is supposed to be much smoother than the accelerometer based code.

I see a lot of examples of pre-iOS5 code, which use accelerometer and older implementations of the AR that use accelerometer code. To rewrite such code, **I need to understand how to map the new CMAttitude and current location into a vector from the current location to some other CLLocation** defined by drawing a vector from the center of the screen, out the back of the iphone towards that reference point.

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the APple pARK sample.. it does a perspective transform that covers the screen then projects the 3D coordinate from your location to the other geo location. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011083